# Merge Fields in Crystal for Chart

Tags: crystal-reports

Anyone know if there is a way to merge several fields (they have the same possible values) in Crystal so they can be used together in a chart?

For example: Field1, Field2 and Field3 all have values of only a 1 or 2. I want to merge all the values from these 3 fields together to show a total of how many 1s there are vs 2s combined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula and chart on that.  You can do whatever operations you want in the formula.